# Fixed header not working if div content is image

Tags: css, cordova

My fixed header code below works in desktop browser but if I run in mobile browser it doesn't.

If I change the content of `'mid_container' div` to `text` it is working.
I don't understand why, if I change it to `image`, it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

```css
#header-wrap {
  background: #eeeeff;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#mid_container {
  background: #fff;
  padding-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-wrap">
  Your menu
  <br/>Link1 Link2 Link3
</div>
<div id="mid_container">
  <img src="img/SMRT-MapSept16.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's working fine
just u try add margin-top to #mid_container{margin-top:50px}
50px same height of header maybe u cannt see the text because behind the header

Comment: it still doesn't work even if I put {marging-top:50px}

Comment: sorry (marging) not correct spelling try again
#mid_container {
  background: #fff;
  padding-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  margin-top:50px;
}

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't work. I am using Cordova to run it in mobile.